# set proxy in package.json to env variable

Tags: node.js, npm

I need to set the `proxy` value in my `package.json` at runtime, like with an environment variable. How could this be done?

```
// package.json
{
  "name": "demo",
  "proxy": process.env.MY_PROXY_VAL , // <- how?
  "dependencies": {},
  "scripts": {},
}
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It will automatically read from `HTTPS_PROXY` or `HTTP_PROXY` so you don't need to do that.

From the [docs](https://docs.npmjs.com/misc/config#https-proxy):

> A proxy to use for outgoing https requests. If the HTTPS_PROXY or https_proxy or HTTP_PROXY or http_proxy environment variables are set, proxy settings will be honored by the underlying request library.

Comment: This doesn't appear to work for me. I have deleted  "proxy": "http://localhost:3002/qat", from my package json and in my .env I have added ```HTTP_PROXY=http://localhost:3002/qat/
HTTPS_PROXY=http://localhost:3002/qat/``` but add both or either of HTTP and HTTPS doesn't allow my API calls to reach the backend service. Getting 404 on the end point.

Comment: This is not working in my case, can you please help me, I have set the env variable, but still its throwing 404

Comment: This doesn't work if you used create-react-app. (https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/issues/1640#issuecomment-328475314)

Comment: Also this answer is misleading because setting the HTTP_PROXY or HTTPS_PROXY variables will overwrite your local system proxy setting for your machine, which is certainly not what the OP wanted. The only valid option I know is to manually define the proxy settings in a setupProxy.js script, as explained here: 
https://create-react-app.dev/docs/proxying-api-requests-in-development/#configuring-the-proxy-manually

Answer (score 5):

So I am converting my comment into an answer, since I think it is important to point out an actual solution to this problem.

I was searching for that exact same answer, and also tried setting the `HTTP_PROXY` and `HTTPS_PROXY` variables via an .env file, and also directly from within a script. However this does not solve the problem since this will overwrite the system proxy settings for the local machine, which I don't think was something the OP intended to do. The result can be that you cannot load npm packages anymore, because of incorrect system proxy settings.

Instead, there is a way of manually configuring the proxy for a CRA in development, as pointed out by the official docs:
https://create-react-app.dev/docs/proxying-api-requests-in-development/#configuring-the-proxy-manually

With this you should create a local `setupProxy.js` file under the `/src` folder of the project, which will then override the proxy set in `package.json`.
Of course then you have to make sure that all the paths are correctly set, but it works well and you have fine grained control over which pages in your app will be proxied and which will not.

To target specifically your question about how to set the proxy via an environment variable, here is an example how you could do it with the `setupProxy` approach and the `createProxyMiddleware`:

```
// Sample of how to setup a proxy middleware with environment variables

//// file: <project_root>/src/setupProxy.js

const { createProxyMiddleware } = require('http-proxy-middleware');

module.exports = function(app) {
  app.use(
    '/rest',
    createProxyMiddleware({
      target: process.env.REACT_APP_PROXY_HOST,
      changeOrigin: true,
    })
  );
};


//// file: <project_root>/.env

REACT_APP_PROXY_HOST=https://localhost:6700
```

In this case I only wanted to proxy requests targeted to the `/rest` endpoint, for which I created a new endpoint. All other requests will still go to the default `localhost:3000` Url, serving the react app.

The host is defined via the environment variable `REACT_APP_PROXY_HOST`. I defined the variable in the local `.env` file, but you could also directly set it inside a script in `package.json` if needed.

**Update**:
Even though the original question was already solved for me, I had an additional issue trying to forward requests to a server running on `https`.
The previous development setup has been fine with the static proxy set in `package.json`. However when using the `createProxyMiddleware` and targeting a server running on https with certificates, the path to the used certificate has to be provided.

```
// Sample of how to setup a proxy middleware with environment variables 
// targeting a server running on https

//// file: <project_root>/src/setupProxy.js

const { createProxyMiddleware } = require('http-proxy-middleware');
const fs = require('fs');

const protocol = JSON.parse(process.env.HTTPS) ? "https:" : "http:";
const host = process.env.REACT_APP_PROXY_HOST
const port = process.env.REACT_APP_PROXY_PORT

module.exports = function(app) {
  app.use(
    '/rest',
    createProxyMiddleware({
      target: {
        protocol: protocol,
        host: host,
        port: port,
        pfx: fs.readFileSync('src/root-cert.pem')
      },
      changeOrigin: true,
    })
  );
};


//// file: <project_root>/.env

HTTPS=true
REACT_APP_PROXY_HOST=localhost
REACT_APP_PROXY_PORT=6700
```

In this case instead of providing the target as a string, it should be given as an object containing `protocol`, `host`, `port` and an attribute `pfx`, which contains the certificate to validate the server via https.
In this case it is a hardcoded path within the project source directory, however it could also be set using environment variables.

The setting `HTTPS=true` overwrites the default development setup and will by default start the development server at `https://localhost:3000`.
With this setting as well as providing the correct certificate the server running on https can be reached without issues.

For reference, this solution is officially linked in the documentation of `http-proxy-middleware` and the underlying `node-http-proxy`:

- https://github.com/chimurai/http-proxy-middleware/blob/master/recipes/https.md
- https://github.com/http-party/node-http-proxy#http---https-using-a-pkcs12-client-certificate

This question also got some attention at other places, e.g.

- https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/issues/3783
- https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/issues/4288
- https://github.com/usc-isi-i2/kgtk-browser/issues/32

Hope to help someone searching for the same problem, if there are any updates to this or things change feel free to add suggestions in the comments.