# How to override proxy settings via command line with Create React App?

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, create-react-app

I set up a React project using Create React App. The development server is configured to proxy API requests via the `proxy` setting in my `package.json`:

```
...
  "proxy": "https://dev-backend.example.com"
...
```

Is there any possibility to override this settings via command line, environment variable or anything similar? I want to be able to change the proxy address in local development without editing the `package.json`, because that often leads to accidentally checking in the wrong proxy address into SCM.

What I want to do is something like this to start a development server that proxies to another backend:

```
$ PROXY=http://localhost:8080 npm start
```

[This GitHub issue](https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/issues/3783) is about the same topic, but doesn't propose an easy solution to achieve the desired functionality.

Answer (score 0):

I searched for an answer to this question as well and found a solution that worked for me.

In short, I used the approach proposed in the official docs:
https://create-react-app.dev/docs/proxying-api-requests-in-development/#configuring-the-proxy-manually

Since I also wanted to set it via an environment variable but didn't find this exact solution anywhere, I posted my own answer here:
[set proxy in package.json to env variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39649298/set-proxy-in-package-json-to-env-variable/71312471#71312471)